# guava osgi bundle download

Tags: java, osgi, guava

The [guava-osgi project site](http://code.google.com/p/guava-osgi/) says I can download the bundle from [their repository](http://guava-osgi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repository/) but I don't see any usable bundles with classes there. Has anyone downloaded their osgi bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an OSGi update site. The contents are in [here](http://guava-osgi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repository/plugins/) and [here](http://guava-osgi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repository/features/). An OSGi container knows that if you point it at the update site.

Here's what I see when I select the update site in Eclipse:

[image: Guava OSGi update site]

Comment: Patrick Flyod - thank you. my idea is not to use in eclipse but in an ear. for now we are not running in osgi enabled app server but just preparing for the future. thx.

Comment: @Pangea I didn't think you'd use it from eclipse, but that was the easiest way for me to demonstrate what's inside the update site

Comment: Since this answer was posted, the guava-osgi project has been discontinued. There is a maven-central artigfact that claims to package an OSGI-compliant version, but that's only released to version 11, the current one is 24 ...